# How to pattern match on multiple things in a for comprehension

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, slick

I have a for comprehension that has `7` things inside it. The `7` things are running DB queries in Slick and might not return any data. When they don't return any data, I want default values put it. I can do the following if there was only `1` thing but how do I do this when I have `7`?

```
case class MyType(one: String, two: Int, three: Int)

//What I could do for 1 thing
for {
  thing1: Option[MyType] <- repo.queryForThing1()
}
yield {
  thing1 match {
   case Some(t) => MyOtherType(Seq(t))
   case None => MyOtherType(Seq(MyType("thing1", 0, 0)))
  }
}

//What do I do for when I have 7 things??
for {
  thing1: Option[MyType] <- repo.queryForThing1()
  thing2: Option[MyType] <- repo.queryForThing2()
  thing3: Option[MyType] <- repo.queryForThing3()
  thing4: Option[MyType] <- repo.queryForThing4()
  thing5: Option[MyType] <- repo.queryForThing5()
  thing6: Option[MyType] <- repo.queryForThing6()
  thing7: Option[MyType] <- repo.queryForThing7()
}
yield {
  thing1 match {
   case Some(t) => MyOtherType(Seq(t))
   case None => MyOtherType(Seq(MyType("thing1", 0, 0)))
  }
}
```

**Question**

How can I pattern match for 7 things? Each one will have default value of `thing<number>` when it is `None`

Comment: Why not just to use `thing1.getOrElse(..)` if all of them have default values? For-comprehension is useful when all values need to be present for something

Comment: That is what I wanted to do and asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55163154/how-to-get-default-values-when-no-records-are-found

Answer (score 1):

Try this! but this is not a sexy code :D

```
for {
  thing1: Option[String] <- repo.queryForThing1()
  thing2: Option[String] <- repo.queryForThing2()
  thing3: Option[String] <- repo.queryForThing3()
  thing4: Option[String] <- repo.queryForThing4()
  thing5: Option[String] <- repo.queryForThing5()
  thing6: Option[String] <- repo.queryForThing6()
  thing7: Option[String] <- repo.queryForThing7()
} yield (thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5, thing6, thing7) match {
  case (a, b, c, c, d, e, f) => ( 
    a.getOrElse("default"),
    b.getOrElse("default"),
    c.getOrElse("default"),
    c.getOrElse("default"),
    d.getOrElse("default"),
    e.getOrElse("default"),
    f.getOrElse("default")
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `MyOtherType` takes a sequence you could create a sequence of queries and map that to the result:

```
Future.sequence(List(
  repo.queryForThing1().map(_.getOrElse(MyType("1", 1, 7))),
  repo.queryForThing2().map(_.getOrElse(MyType("2", 2, 6))),
  repo.queryForThing3().map(_.getOrElse(MyType("3", 3, 5))),
  repo.queryForThing4().map(_.getOrElse(MyType("4", 4, 4))),
  repo.queryForThing5().map(_.getOrElse(MyType("5", 5, 3))),
  repo.queryForThing6().map(_.getOrElse(MyType("6", 6, 2))),
  repo.queryForThing7().map(_.getOrElse(MyType("7", 7, 1)))
)).map(MyOtherType)
```

However this is different from the original code in that it performs all the queries at the same time rather than sequentially, and won't stop early if one of the queries fails.

The fact that you have seven different queries and seven different defaults means that you are going to have to write them out individually so it is always going to look a little messy.

---

For reference, here is a version that performs the queries in series rather than in parallel, but it isn't pretty!

```
val queries =
  List(
    repo.queryForThing1 _ -> MyType("1", 1, 7),
    repo.queryForThing2 _ -> MyType("2", 2, 6),
    repo.queryForThing3 _ -> MyType("3", 3, 5),
    repo.queryForThing4 _ -> MyType("4", 4, 4),
    repo.queryForThing5 _ -> MyType("5", 5, 3),
    repo.queryForThing6 _ -> MyType("6", 6, 2),
    repo.queryForThing7 _ -> MyType("7", 7, 1)
  )

queries.foldLeft(Future.successful(Vector.empty[MyType])) {
  case (prev, (query, default)) =>
    prev.flatMap(p => query().map(q => p :+ q.getOrElse(default)))
}.map(MyOtherType)
```